# Azure Function writing to CosmosDb - topology

Tags: azure-functions

Workflow:

1. App service puts message in a Queue Storage
2. Azure Function, triggered by Queue, picks up message and process it
3. Function should write its results into Cosmos DB (that could be create/replace/delete document)

Basically, there are 2 ways of doing it:

1. Bind `DocumentClient` into Function and do CosmosDB job directly from Function
2. Have Function call predefined http endpoint in App Service which actually does Cosmos DB job.
3. Have callback endpoint integrated into queue message (its a variance od 2)

I prefer options 2/3 where Function is pure wiring/brokering block between Queue and AppService most for the reason that App Service has fully repository for handling CosmosDB part.

Question is:

Is there any strong reason to have any kind of CosmosDB specifics inside Function?

Comment: this is overengineering. why do you need function to call App Service to tell it to process something? Just have app service listen to the queue

Comment: @4c74356b41 could you comment/elaborate on how does app service listening to queues work in failure scenarios?

Comment: @4c74356b41 app service listening to the queue? to be honest i wasnt even thinking of this scenario mainly because of the nature of web application pool/recycling (i am aware of AlwaysOn but still, wouldnt like to rely on it for this). or you mean using app services web jobs for it? could you please elaborate a bit more? tnx